# Problems with Sending message to MSMQ

Tags: c#, msmq

I have a scenario where in i have to send a message to the msmq below in the format of message header + payload. Below is the example.

```
        Person Message
        <? Xml version="1.0"?>
        <Person>
        <Employee>
         <Name>Manthan</name>
        </employee>
        </Person>
```

How to send above message to msmq, i have tried all possible solution but still no success. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Below is the code

```
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       sb.Append("Person Message"); 
       sb.Append("<?XML Version=\"1.0\">");
       sb.Append("<Person>");
       sb.Append("<Employee>");
       sb.Append("<Name>Manthan</Name>");
       sb.Append("</Employee>");
       sb.Append("</Person>");

      MessageQueue  msMq = new MessageQueue(MQPath);
      msmq.Send(sb.tostring());
```

Output in MSMQ is

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
         <string>Person Message&lt;?XML       Version="1.0"&gt;&lt;Person&gt;&lt;Employee&gt;&lt;Name&gt;Manthan&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;/Employee&gt;&lt;/Person&gt;</string>
```

Above message is not same as expected output how to get the expected output

Comment: Hi Gutblender,

Sorry I am posting question first time so forgot to mentioned details.. I create a string with xml tags and appended string header to it but when i try to place that message in queue.. It display in format <?xml Version="1.0"?> <string> Person Message &lt; xml version="1.0"? &gt; etc.. In short < is getting converted to &lt; when placed on queue and unnecessary xml tag <string> and <?xml Version="1.0"> is getting created.

Comment: you need to show more than xml here what does the C# code behind look like..

Comment: the message is a string, the string object is getting serialized when it is put into the queue, as far as i am aware you cannot turn that behavior off. You should create a class to represent the desired data structure and pass that directly to the send method.

Comment: Can you just give me a small example i will try to implement.. It would be great help

Comment: It looks like doing a `toString()` on `StringBuilder` object is XML encoding the data you put in there. Try to put all the data in a single line string like `var personData = @"Person Message <?XML Version=\"1.0\"><Person><Employee><Name>Manthan</name></employee></Person>"` and sending it as `msmq.Send(personData)`.

Comment: Why do you need to put a message in the queue?  What is the consumer of the queue?  The reason I ask is that .NET uses different default formatting than COM.  If the consumer is .NET, the easiest way (IMO) to use a WCF service as the consumer and just add a service reference to the service from your .NET sender.  Good example here (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/326909/Creating-a-WCF-Service-with-MSMQ-Communication-and).  If not .NET to .NET, take a look at the message formatters to see what's appropriate (e.g. ActiveXMessageFormatter)

Comment: Adam47, Thanks for the answer consumer uses a third party tool to consume this messages, I have asked them for some flexibility at thier side but they only need message in the format which i have mentioned in the question thats the problem.

Comment: Venkatapthi, I tried our solution but still same problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSMQ put messages in SOAP you will have to deserialize the results
....

```
MessageQueue  msMq = new MessageQueue(MQPath);
msmq.Send(sb.tostring());

Message[] msgs = msMq.GetAllMessages();

foreach (var msg in msgs)
      {
            System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(msg.BodyStream);
            MSGtext = reader.ReadToEnd();

            string MSGValue = (string)XmlDeserializeFromString(MSGtext);

        }
 }
 public object XmlDeserializeFromString(string objectData)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string));
        object result;

        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(objectData))
        {
            result = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: HI Stuart,

Thank you for the answer but the application which is reading my message want message in format what i have mentioned in the question. Its third party application and they don't want implement above logic to deserialize the message. There is no flexiblity at thier end.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to create a custom message formatter

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         sb.Append("Person Message");
         sb.Append("<?XML Version=\"1.0\">");
         sb.Append("<Person>");
         sb.Append("<Employee>");
         sb.Append("<Name>Manthan</Name>");
         sb.Append("</Employee>");
         sb.Append("</Person>");

         //write to Queue
         msMq.Formatter = new ActiveXMessageFormatter();
         msMq.Send(sb.ToString());

         //read From Queue
         MessageQueue  msMqReader = new MessageQueue(MQPath);
         msMqReader.Formatter = new ActiveXMessageFormatter();         

         Message msg = msMqReader.Receive();
         Console.WriteLine(msg.Body);
```

}

Comment: Hi Stuart,

Thanks for the answer but as i told before my problem is there will no logic written in the application which is consuming this message because it is a third party app and they don't want to go back to that third party and ask them to write deserailzation logic.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your comment until today. This solution should now work for you to deserialize and serialize strings in MSMQ.

Comment: Hi Stuart,

Thanks for your comment but as i said earlier my client is using a thirdparty tool which internally reads the message from MSMQ.. They don't have flexibility to write c# code at thier end because tool doesn't allow that so they cannot desearliaze the message..

Comment: The above example has both the reading and writing to the Queue for testing purposes... It writes a string with no soap formatting into the Queue... If the encoding is correct the third party application should be able to grab the message out. The message writing will be Person Message <?XML Version=\"1.0\"> <Person> ....

Comment: Message written in the queue was in binary format. Below is the message..


50 65 72 73 6F 6E 20 4D Person M
65 73 73 61 67 65 3C 3F essage<?
58 4D 4C 20 56 65 72 73 XML Vers
69 6F 6E 3D 22 31 2E 30 ion="1.0
22 3E 3C 50 65 72 73 6F "><Perso
6E 3E 3C 45 6D 70 6C 6F n><Emplo
79 65 65 3E 3C 4E 61 6D yee><Nam
65 3E 4D 61 6E 74 68 61 e>Mantha
6E 3C 2F 4E 61 6D 65 3E n</Name>
3C 2F 45 6D 70 6C 6F 79 </Employ
65 65 3E 3C 2F 50 65 72 ee></Per
73 6F 6E 3E             son>